# Identify SharePoint Designer Workflows using Custom actions

Tags: 2007, designer-workflow, workflow-activity

We have a very large Web Applications which has around hundred OOB workflows and some might be using custom actions as well.

How can I get the list of the workflows which are using these custom actions?

Do I need to manually open each workflow to see the presence??

Answer (score -1):

I think the best solution will be to write simple PowerShell script which will bypass all workflows and look for custom namespaces and custom workflow actions.

As the basis for your script you can check out the [following link](http://everythingsharepoint2010.blogspot.ru/2013/04/get-all-lists-with-workflow.html)

Comment: Please add more details from your link to your post, if the link breaks your answer will not be as helpful as it could be